# How to read a rely ratings: compressor: 10(10)A, p.f.0.6? what does p.f.0.6 stand for?

Tags: relay

just like title, I've got a specification of cooler controller, but do not know how to read them.
relay rating
compressor: 10(10)A,p.f.0.6
light:      4(4)A,p.f.0.6
Fan:        4(4)A,p.f.0.6

thanks for help

Comment: It might be helpful to provide a picture or a part number

Answer (score 1):

[Power factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor), the ratio of real power to apparent power used by the device.